# Who is Mir's Mind Guardian?

Tags: ar-tonelico

In *Ar Tonelico 2: Melody of Metafalica*, in the talk topic *Mind Guardian?* (Lv 3) when Croix asks if Mir has a Mind Guardian she says at one point

> You are just unaware of her. You must have met her in my Cosmosphere by now

However after her "story" finishes Ayatane introduces himself as Mir's Guardian (he doesn't say Mind Guardian though).

Now according to [this GameFAQs guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/939100-ar-tonelico-ii-melody-of-metafalica/faqs/56100), the requirement to unlock this talk topic is

> After completing Jacqli's Cosmosphere Lv 3

but I haven't seen anyone who could be a Mind Guardian but Ayatane. So who is Mir's Mind Guardian and where would Croix have met her before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Ayatane. Mir says "her" because the translators who did the talk topics weren't the same as the ones who worked in the Cosmospheres and main storyline, so it's simply a translation error of the many the official NISA localization had.

The fan relocalization has that (and many other errors and bugs) fixed.

Comment: I don't think this needs additional references, so I've removed the post notice to that effect. @aquagon is clearly quite familiar with Ar Tonelico (cf. http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/35936/) in both English and Japanese, so I think it's safe to assume OP isn't pulling these answers from their nether regions.