# What does "gal" mean in Hajimete no Gal and/or Japanese culture?

Tags: hajimete-no-gal

In the anime [Hajimete no Gal (aka My First Girlfriend is a Gal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_First_Girlfriend_is_a_Gal), it's made abundantly clear in the first episode that "gal" is not just another feminine pronoun.  Based on the 2 "gals" in the show, and compared to the other girls in the show, it seems there's a marked difference in style, personality, and appearance to be labeled a "gal".

What is a "gal" in anime or Japanese culture?

Comment: possibly related: [What is a “gal wife”?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/35905/what-is-a-gal-wife)

Comment: That was an auto-recommendation, and it's not related.  That question is very specific to the anime/game the OP is asking about.

Comment: actually it wasn't an "auto-recommendation". rather i thought it was possibly related in which a gal girlfriend might be similar to a gal wife. i could be wrong however which is why i said possibly related rather than duplicate

Comment: An article on Crunchyroll about the series touches on this topic: http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-feature/2017/07/20-1/elite-classrooms-and-gal-friends-get-hooked-on-these-new-summer-anime

Comment: @memor-x By "auto-recommendation", I meant the site recommended it as I was typing up the question.

Comment: I'm guessing [Galo Sengen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EKTw50Uf8M) has already faded from public memory?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Gal" is the English transliteration for [*gyaru*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyaru), which is a fashion trend in Japanese culture.  This fashion trend includes things like:

- Tanning/darkening the skin
- Wearing lots of shiny makeup (traditional Japanese culture is very modest with makeup)
- Wearing lots of jewelry and has lots of accessories (fake nails, excessive nail/toe polish)

Effectively, the "gals" in *My First Girlfriend is a Gal* are following the *gyaru* fashion trend.

Answer (score 7):

Can't comment yet so I'll add an answer.

ギャル (*gyaru*) is actually the way they imported the English word "girl".

Then they imported the English slang "gal" on top of that as a back-*Romaji*-ized name for the current fashion.

(In addition to what Makoto said.)

If you can read the Japanese, here's a dictionary entry, but it doesn't help much:

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/en/ギャル/m0u/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/en/%E3%82%AE%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AB/m0u/)

Here's a wikipedia entry:

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ギャル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AE%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AB)

And here it is in English:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyaru

The Japanese is more complete and more interesting, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a bit of a deeper meaning and as to why this trend came about. It goes way back to the World War 2 and a bit before. After occupation to make money, girls would well prostitute themselves, so a tanned girl was also a sign that they were out on the corner a lot. In the rebellion days of youth, in the 80s, it was a way to rebel in Asia, so it became a popular trend.

This is why you also get that "gals" are sluts or whores. In the west though, tanning became a positive thing while in the east it became a negative thing. Also why in the anime and the manga of *Hajimete no Gal*, the ex calls her a "slut". Also, *Hajimete no Gal* directly translates to "first time gal".